# HTML form submits and the hostname changes to IP address

Tags: proxy, jakarta-ee

I am facing a peculiar problem. The problem is, my webapp is being installed behind a proxy. The request gets submitted to the proxy which forwards the request to the original host that is running the websphere web application. 
The problem I am facing is, when I access the webapp, its URL looks like the below

```
http://www.myproxy.com
```

Lets say I get a form on this URL, when I submit the form, it is getting submitted to another URL - http://10.1.2.87

Since the URL is changing, application server thinks it is a different session and throws the login page again. The login page comes thru a filter which checks whether user is already authenticated in the session or not.
I do not have much knowledge on proxy settings .. where do you think is the problem?

Comment: Why downgraded ? Is it a stupid thing to ask ?

Comment: No idea, possibly because it's in no way related to HTML (which you thus incorrectly tagged; I've removed it) and after all not really programming related (belongs on serverfault), or s/he didn't find the question useful at all and/or s/he had such a bad day to do it without leaving a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thus, you're using a reverse proxy. You need to configure it to manage the sessions as well. To the point, it should send the HTTP `Cookie` and `Set-Cookie` headers forth and back as well. Consult the documentation of the proxy in question for details or ask at [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com) for detailed assistance (don't forget to mention which proxy you're using).